# Vora 1.4 services are not starting

Tags: vora

i have installed vora 1.4 on single node cluster with 1 core and 32 gb of ram..my vora got installed successfully but mine services are not starting...

this is my **
**.......
/opt/vora/lib/vora-catalog/bin/v2catalog_server: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /opt/vora/lib/vora-v2server/lib/libv2runtime.so.1)
/opt/vora/lib/vora-catalog/bin/v2catalog_server: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version`GLIBCXX_3.4.17' not found (required by /opt/vora/lib/vora-v2server/lib/libv2runtime.so.1)
/opt/vora/lib/vora-catalog/bin/v2catalog_server: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by /opt/vora/lib/vora-v2server/lib/libv2runtime.so.1)
/opt/vora/lib/vora-catalog/bin/v2catalog_server: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version`GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by /opt/vora/lib/vora-v2server/lib/libv2runtime.so.1)
/opt/vora/lib/vora-catalog/bin/v2catalog_server: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.7' not found (required by /opt/vora/lib/vora-v2server/lib/libv2runtime.so.1)

**vora-disk.logs**
Database server started at Mon Aug 07 2017 15:03
Trying to start SharedMemory link ...
    SharedMemory link started successfully
Trying to start TCPIP link ...
Starting on port 2638
    TCPIP link started successfully
Now accepting requests
Database server shutdown due to TERM signal
TCPIP listener on IP address (::):2638 is exiting
TCPIP listener on IP address 0.0.0.0:2638 is exiting
Database server stopped at Mon Aug 07 2017 15:04
SAP IQ
Version 16.0
(64bit mode)
Copyright 1992-2016 by SAP AG or an SAP affiliate company. All rights reserved
Copyright (c) 2015 SAP SE or an SAP affiliate company.
All rights reserved.
Use of this software is governed by the Sybase License Agreement.
Refer to http://www.sybase.com/softwarelicenses.

Processors detected: 1
Maximum number of processors the server will use: 1 physical processor(s), 1 core(s)
Running Linux 2.6.32-696.6.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jul 12 14:17:22 UTC 2017 on X86_64
Server built for X86_64 processor architecture
8296K of memory used for caching
Minimum cache size: 8296K, maximum cache size: 262144K
Using a maximum page size of 4096 bytes
/opt/vora/lib/vora-v2node/bin/v2node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /opt/vora/lib/vora-v2server/lib/libv2diagnostics.so)
/opt/vora/lib/vora-v2node/bin/v2node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version`GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /opt/vora/lib/vora-v2server/lib/libv2diagnostics.so)
/opt/vora/lib/vora-v2node/bin/v2node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /opt/vora/lib/vora-v2server/lib/libv2auth.so)
/opt/vora/lib/vora-v2node/bin/v2node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version`CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by /opt/vora/lib/vora-v2server/lib/libv2runtime.so.1)
/opt/vora/lib/vora-v2node/bin/v2node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /opt/vora/lib/vora-v2server/lib/libv2runtime.so.1)
/opt/vora/lib/vora-v2node/bin/v2node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version`GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /opt/vora/lib/vora-v2server/lib/libv2runtime.so.1)
/opt/vora/lib/vora-v2node/bin/v2node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.17' not found (required by /opt/vora/lib/vora-v2server/lib/libv2runtime.so.1)
/opt/vora/lib/vora-v2node/bin/v2node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version`GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by /opt/vora/lib/vora-v2server/lib/libv2runtime.so.1)
/opt/vora/lib/vora-v2node/bin/v2node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by /opt/vora/lib/vora-v2server/lib/libv2runtime.so.1)
/opt/vora/lib/vora-v2node/bin/v2node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version`CXXABI_1.3.7' not found (required by /opt/vora/lib/vora-v2server/lib/libv2runtime.so.1)
Multiprogramming level: 150
Automatic tuning of multiprogramming level is disabled

Comment: Anything in the logs? (/var/log/vora/vora-manager/  or /var/log/messages)?

Comment: Anything running on that node? (ps -efa | grep vora) On the Vora Manager master you should see consul server, nomad server+client, and vora-manager-gui.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that you do not have the C++ compat libraries installed. Installing the compat libraries will solve that issue (compat-sap-c++). Be aware that for Vora 1.4 you need version 4.8.x (the older 4.7.x will not work).

See the following SAP Notes for details:

- [2213226 - Prerequisites for installing SAP Vora: Operating Systems and Hadoop Components](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2213226)
- [2228351 - Linux: SAP HANA Database SPS 11 revision 110 (or higher) on RHEL 6 or SLES 11](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2228351)